# Very high latency caused by router?

Tags: router, ping, latency

I'm getting very high pings (2000-10000ms), and intermittent internet connection when using a wireless router (be it on LAN or WAN). When connecting a desktop directly to the cable modem, there are no issues so I think I've isolated the problem to the router. However, even after a factory reset to the router the issue still persists. It began a few days ago and was intermittent, but is now permanent. If I ping from the desktop or from the router control page itself, I get the same results (2000-10000ms). Some websites do not respond to pings at all, while some do. I also get very high pings on Google DNS (8.8.8.8).

Comment: What if you plug wired into the wifi router?  Can you isolate whether it is the router itself, or the wifi connection to the router?

Comment: The same issues occur if I am wired to the wifi router so I think it may be the router itself. I've also tried replacing the physical cable between the router and the modem, and the router and PC.

Comment: Is the problem just with synthetic tools like ping? Or do you see issues in real world applications? Do your upload/download rates (measures with speedtest or similar) show an issue?

Comment: How is the router connected to the cable modem?  Via LAN ports or WAN port?  If the former, have you disabled DHCP on one or the other?

Comment: The problem is not just with the tools. Some websites will not load at all, some will load very inconsistently. If I manage to get a speed test site to load, the connection speed is fine. The problem is getting one to actually load. As for the router, it is wired to the modem.

Comment: The modem is a D-Link DIR-655. I turned off a setting called "Advanced DNS" and specified Google's DNS instead and everything seems to be working correctly now. Maybe the issue was just with whatever DNS D-Link was using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling Advanced DNS Service on D-Link routers causes it to route DNS requests through a service called OpenDNS.  Unchecking it will instead use your ISPs DNS servers, or you can manually configure other DNS servers to use.  It could be that there are/were some network path issues between your router and the OpenDNS servers your D-Link router was attempting to use, or the OpenDNS servers may have been suffering from issues of their own (network issues, DoS attack, etc).  I usually use my ISP's DNS servers, unless I'm finding that their DNS servers are laggy, in which case I switch to Google Public DNS - IP address `8.8.8.8`.